# MVC, is M model of domain or it is confined and prepared data?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, design-patterns

I m working on a MVC web app. I am just wondering is M, domain model or poco classes or it is refined and processed data ready to be sent to View for display ?

For example consider a database table:

```
Id, Name, Salary
```

To Display I need 4 columns instead of 3:

```
Id, Name, Salary, Annual Salary (Salary * 12)
```

I am confuse as per pattern guideline what will be in my Model class, will I do `AnnualSalary=Salary*12` in Controller and pass all 4 pieces of data to view or my Model will return 4 columns ?

Another point is that if I need to Add Address from other table with these 4 columns, should Model return refined and required data or in controller I should query 2 different data tables and further select and pass data to View ?

Comment: There's often a confusion between view model and data model (or business model).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good practice on ASP.NET MVC can be to separate Model from Database and Model for the View.
On your case, we will have two model : EmployeeDTO and Employee.

```
public class EmployeeDTO
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Salary { get; set; }
}

public class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Salary { get; set; }
    public int AnnualSalary { get { return this.Salary * 12; } } 
}
```

After, on your Controller, you will map the EmployeeDTO to Employee (to read action), and Employee to EmployeeDTO (to create/update actions).
For example, a Read method :

```
public ActionResult Read(int id)
{
    EmployeeDTO employeeDTO = db.Employee.Find(id);
    Employee employee = new Employee()
    {
        Id = employeeDTO.Id,
        Name = employeeDTO.Name,
        Salary = employeeDTO.Salary
    };
    return View(employee);
}
```

With this approche, you can implement DataAnnotations for EmployeeDTO that's not automatically apply to Employee (so to your View) and vice versa.
In your case, you can add a new property that not impact the database schema.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Usually, DTO = Data Transfer Object, only appropriate here when the Controller is fed from a Service. Not in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Based on MVC pattern, Controller is responsible to provide all information that View requires to make itself. In Addition, a ViewModel is a class that can be combination of all information for view from different sources.

So, it's recommended that your `Annual Salary` calculated in your Controller, put in ViewModel and the ViewModel sent to the view.

It's very effective and popular method among developers.

> When you have dozens of distinct values to pass to a view, the same flexibility that allows you to 
>   quickly add a new entry, or rename an existing one, becomes your worst enemy .You are left on your 
>   own to track item names and values; you get no help from Microsoft IntelliSense and compilers .
>   **The only proven way to deal with complexity in software is through appropriate design. So defining an object model for each view helps you track what that view really needs. I suggest you define a 
>   view-model class for each view you add to the application**.

-- "Programming Microsoft ASP.NET MVC" by Dino Esposito

**Update:**

My assumption is that `Annual Salary` is a ViewModel property not a business property.

Comment: 'it's recommended that your Annual Salary calculated in your Controller'. Is it? By whom? Looks like domain logic leaking into the controller to me.

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of how you communicate with the View, the Annual Salary calculation is domain logic and should, therefore, be part of your domain model.

Letting domain logic leak into you controller looks risky to me.

Answer (score 0):

> I am just wondering is M, domain model or poco classes or it is refined and processed data ready to be sent to View for display ?

The MVC pattern is losely defined and there is no 1-1 mapping between M,V,C and classes.

The model is everything used to get the information required by the view. Hence it's your repository/wcf client/dto/entity etc.

The pattern doesn't really care how you fetch the information, what it consists of or how the information is structured. It just says that the Controller should get information from the Model and give it to the View.

Now, ASP.NET MVC uses ViewModels which are intended to be used as adapters for the Model information and therefore adapt it so that the View doesn't have to contain logic to transform the information.

The VM itself could use your entities, your repositories etc. But typically the best approach is if just uses your entities (to make the controllers cleaner).